# How can I implement IP anonymity in my application? Is there an open source API for this?

Tags: ip, tor, anonymity

I was thinking about two options:

1. [Tor](https://stem.torproject.org/)
2. [Mix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mix_network)

But I don't know how to include any of this in my application.

I'm building a protocol for transfering small files (1 to 5 MB) and I want to hide the sender's IP. I will be building a native windows/linux/mac application.

I'm planning to have many computers inside the system, so I was thinking that using MIX and routing through them could be a nice idea.

I found this [gMix](https://svs.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/gmix/implementations.php) framework. I tried to develop on top of the framework but it looks very complicated. I'm thinking about developing my own Mix implementation for this project.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to go.

"*Tarzan is a peer-to-peer anonymous IP network overlay. Because it provides IP service, Tarzan is general-purpose and transparent to applications. Organized as a decentralized peer-to-peer overlay, Tarzan is fault-tolerant, highly scalable, and easy to manage.Tarzan achieves its anonymity with layered encryption and multi-hop routing, much like a Chaumian mix. A message initiator chooses a path of peers pseudo-randomly through a restricted topology in a way that adversaries cannot easily influence. Cover traffic prevents a global observer from using traffic analysis to identify an initiator. Protocols toward unbiased peer-selection offer new directions for distributing trust among untrusted entities.Tarzan provides anonymity to either clients or servers, without requiring that both participate. In both cases, Tarzan uses a network address translator (NAT) to bridge between Tarzan hosts and oblivious Internet hosts.Measurements show that Tarzan imposes minimal overhead over a corresponding non-anonymous overlay route.*"

You can find the package in this [link](https://gnunet.org/tarzan%3Accs02).